# Can I use await async inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm an a newbie studying promises and async/await and would like to know if it's possible to change this code:

```
async function waiting() {
   let a = await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('A'), 1e3))
   let b = await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('B'), 2e3))
   let c = await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('C'), 3e3))
   console.log(a, b, c)
}

waiting()
```

And use something like this:

`let a = await async () => setTimeout(() =>  'A', 1e3)`

or similiar.

**Update**:

I also tried this:

`let a = await (() => setTimeout(() => 'A', 1e3))()`

I want to achieve the same with a shortened syntax.

Comment: That defines a function but never calls it.

Comment: "would like to know if it's possible to change this code" The best way to answer this question is to try it and see what happens.

Comment: Johnny that would not work, because the async function is not awaiting on setTimeout's callback

Comment: if you really want this, you can create an "asyncify" wrapper function that hides the details by wrapping callbackfn with an async function.

Comment: I wanted to achieve the same with a shortened `async` syntax. I thought using `async` I would turn everything into a Promise so being able to achieve the same. I tried many combinations but after readying all your wonderful help/knowledge I think it's not possible! Also I learnt that using just `await` a function becomes a Promise but `setTimeout` doesn't return anything `let a = await (() => setTimeout(() => 'A', 1e3))()` Thank you so much, you all are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Not with setTimeout as it doesn't return anything, but with real async methods you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> The `Promise.all()` method returns a single `Promise` that fulfills when
>   all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled

```
let [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([methodA(), methodB(), methodC()]);
```

Comment: That is different than what the O.P. shows. The O.P.'s  code waits serially for `a` to settle, then `b` to settle, and finally, for `c` to settle. You code kicks off all 3 asynchronous tasks essentially simultaneously, then waits until all 3 have settled. Those are 2 very different processes, and you code introduces a race condition. If those 3 tasks affect global state or have other side effects, you can have bugs that are very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Careful, `Promise.all` is absolutely not the same as OP's code. His code is completely sequential, each promise waiting for the previous one to finish before starting, while yours runs "in parallel" (or more specifically, they can finish in any order and are started sequentially).

Comment: If he just wants to `console.log(a, b , c)` once everything is ready, should do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *yes*. Awaiting anything turns it into a promise. You could say something like

```
// not asynchronous; not a promise
function foo() { return 3; }
. . .
async function do_it() {
  const x  = await foo();
}
```

`foo()` essentially gets wrapped with something like

```
new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    resolve(foo());
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
}
```

So you could say something like:

```
const sleep = ms  => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( () => resolve(), ms) );

async function waiting() {

   await sleep(1000);
   const a = await computeA();
   await sleep(2000);
   const b = await computeB();
   await sleep(3000);
   const c = await computeC();

   console.log(a, b, c)

}
```

`async`/`await` allows one to express things in a more procedural looking manner. It also surrenders the event loop: other things can continue to process while you're waiting.

Comment: maybe this is what OP wants, but it doesn't seem like it?  what you've provided is basically the exact same thing as he did in the example of what he doesn't want to do.  he mentioned async later indicating he wants to achieve the same with a shortened async syntax.  a common misunderstanding in thinking that async directly replaces all use cases for Promise wrapping.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nicholas Carey, I didn't know that "Awaiting anything turns it into a promise" I thought that I need `async` that's why I use it like this: `await async () => setTimeout(() =>  'A', 1e3)`. So, `async` returns a promise and 'await' resolves anything as a promise! Awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much @user120242 yes, as you said I wanted to achieve the same with a shortened async syntax. I thought using `async` I would turn everything into a Promise so being able to achieve the same. I tried many combinations but after readying all your wonderful help/knowledge I think it's not possible!

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny: it's the `async` that makes the function return a promise (and enables the use of `await` within it). You can `await` pretty much anything. If you `await` a non-promise, you get that value. If you `await` a Promise, it will wait and yield the event loop until the Promise settles (resolves or rejects). If it resolves, you'll that value. If it rejects, the `async` function executing when `await` was called returns a rejected promise.